# how to print a message with stopifnot in R

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to make a function with 2 o more parameter, and I want check if the first parameter is a list, so if it's not a list, stop and then print a message

I have tried

```
myfunction <- function(x, y){
     #check if it a list  
     if (!is.list(x)){
          stop("Error: x must be a list")
     }
    # if x is a list keep going with the rest of the code  

}
```

or if I use stopifnot how can I add a message

```
myfunction <- function(x, y){
         #check if it a list  
         stopifnot(is.list(x)) 
           print("Error: x must be a list")
        # if x is a list keep going with the rest of the code 
    
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: see try() and try_catch()  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/try

Comment: Works well, just a typo, it's `function` not `funtion`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use named arguments, which will become the error message:

```r
myfunction <- function(x, y) {
  stopifnot("Error: x must be a list" = is.list(x)) 
}

myfunction(1, 2)
#> Error in myfunction(1, 2): Error: x must be a list
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>